# Install Snap from a list file

Tags: snap

I can get a list of installed snaps, but what if I have a new laptop, and need to install all snaps listed by `snap list`?

Answer (score 4):

> and need to install all snaps listed by `snap list`?

So you are using the `snap list` command to list all the snap packages. When we call `snap list` it prints many rows and columns (similar to `dpkg -l`), for example on my machine:

```
$ snap list
Name               Version             Rev    Tracking         Publisher   Notes
bare               1.0                 5      latest/stable    canonical*  base
core18             20211215            2284   latest/stable    canonical*  base
core20             20220114            1328   latest/stable    canonical*  base
gnome-3-34-1804    0+git.3556cb3       77     latest/stable/…  canonical*  -
gnome-3-38-2004    0+git.1f9014a       99     latest/stable    canonical*  -
gtk-common-themes  0.1-59-g7bca6ae     1519   latest/stable/…  canonical*  -
snap-store         3.38.0-66-gbd5b8f7  558    latest/stable/…  canonical*  -
snapd              2.54.3              14978  latest/stable    canonical*  snapd
```

So, you **can't** simply run `sudo snap install $(cat snap-list.txt)`.

You need to use the `awk` utility to print only the names of the packages.

1. Run `snap list > snap-list` on the machine you have installed all your snap packages.
2. Transfer the `snap-list` file to your new laptop.
3. Open a terminal and `cd` into the directory containing the `snap-list` file.
4. Run the following command:

   ```sh
   awk -F "\t" 'NR>1 {print $1}' snap-list | xargs sudo snap install
   ```

Comment: Just tried and it says: only one snap file can be installed at a time...

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```sh
cut -d ' ' -f 1 snap-list | grep -v Name | xargs -n 1 sudo snap install
```

This

- takes the first column from the `snap-list` file (delimited by spaces),
- discards "Name" as it's just a heading,
- and runs `sudo snap install` for each row